# Alter Email Body with Gmail API

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

The [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) offers a method for modifying the labels of a messages. Can it be used for altering other parts of the message like the subject or the body?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From Gmail API documentation:

> Messages are immutable: they can only be created and deleted. No
>   message properties can be changed other than the labels applied to a
>   given message.

More on this here https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/?hl=ru
You can, however, dynamically construct and send new messages.

Comment: It might be possible. For instance, here's an [extn](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rename-email/miepnlkmnjdfcnkplikgackpobfmaifb) that can change the email subject. It does this using the Gmail API.